# problem in getting the exact size of the image from photo gallery in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I'm selecting a photo from the photo library which is 480* 320  and I want to keep at as back ground to my view which is of same size(480,320). But I'm getting image in 320,480 size . (what happening here is I'm getting one and half image as back ground). can anyone please help me. I'm attaching the screen shot with this post

[image]

I want to get 480,320 image directly from the gallery or by taking picture.

Thanks in advance.
Praveena!

-(void)reloadView
{

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myFirstView];
printf("\n this is in loadView method");
CartoonMakerAppDelegate *appDelegate=(CartoonMakerAppDelegate*)[ [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

UIImage *img ;
if(appDelegate.isbgFromDevice == YES)
{
    img = [UIImage imageWithData:appDelegate.imageData];
    appDelegate.bgImage = img;
    appDelegate.isbgFromDevice = NO;
}
else if(appDelegate.isbgFromLibrary == YES)
{
    NSString *bgStr = appDelegate.backgroundImage;
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:bgStr];
    appDelegate.isbgFromLibrary = NO;
    appDelegate.bgImage = img;
}
NSData *bgImgdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(appDelegate.bgImage);
if([bgImgdata length]!=0)
{

    myFirstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:appDelegate.bgImage];
    myFirstView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you set contentMode property of your view?

Comment: I set it as default       myFirstView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

Comment: Can you add code where you load image and display it?